# Как через Python отправлять JavaScript команды сайту?

Tags: javascript, python

Я хочу через python отправлять JS скрипт сайту так, чтобы это было равносильно написанию этого скрипта в консоль f12. Как такое реализовать и можно ли вообще это сделать?

Comment: Если и скрипт на Python, и браузер с сайтом управляются вами, можно попробовать https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer (консольные команды можно выполнять при помощи `page.evaluate()`, например).

Comment: Что значит "Управляются вами"? То есть нужно открыть вручную браузер?

Comment: Можно подключаться к уже открытому браузеру, но скрипт может открывать браузер сам (видимый или невидимый). То есть и скрипт, и сайт будут работать на вашем компьютере. Если вам нужно отсылать команды на браузеры других пользователей сайта, этот способ не подходит.